# Stanford POStagger demo fails on Windows

Tags: stanford-nlp, pos-tagger

I am trying to run the Stanford POSTagger (version 3.6) using the Windows cmd and I am having problems. I am following the instructions in the README with the corrections for Windows.
I have a directory (C:\Program Files\stanford-postagger-full-2015-12-09>)with the POSTagger files.
In the command prompt I am at this directory (..Stanford-postagger-full...).
1)The command: javac -cp stanford-postagger.jar TaggerDemo.java is executed correctly (no error message)
2)The command: java -cp ".;stanford-postagger.jar" TaggerDemo models\wsj-0-18-left3words.tagger sample-input.txt fails. I am getting the following error:

> C:\Program Files\stanford-postagger-full-2015-12-09>java -cp
>   ".;stanford-postagger.jar" TaggerDemo
>   models\wsj-0-18-left3words.tagger sample-input.txt 
>   Exception in thread
>   "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/LoggerFactory
>           at edu.stanford.nlp.io.IOUtils.(IOUtils.java:42)
>           at edu.stanford.nlp.tagger.maxent.MaxentTagger.readModelAndInit(MaxentTagger.java:765)
>           at edu.stanford.nlp.tagger.maxent.MaxentTagger.(MaxentTagger.java:298)
>           at edu.stanford.nlp.tagger.maxent.MaxentTagger.(MaxentTagger.java:263)
>           at TaggerDemo.main(TaggerDemo.java:20) Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.slf4j.LoggerFactory
>           at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
>           at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
>           ... 5 more

Any suggestions about my error? Am I at the correct directory to run the commands?

Answer (score 0):

I believe there is another `.jar` file that you need to add to the classpath. If you look at the error, you'll see that the class that isn't found is `org/slf4j/LoggerFactory`, which is in `.\lib\slf4j.jar`.

On a side note, you might want to get a program like [7zip](http://www.7-zip.org/), which allows you a convenient (right-click) method for viewing the contents of `.zip` and `.jar` (etc) files. That way, you'll be able to find those classes that you can't find otherwise.

Hope that helps—I'm still new to java.